# Can I inject a browserify build into an html document on the fly?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, browserify

Is it possible to run a node web server locally and have it inject code into an html file? Let's say I have a file called test.html which I want to inject a browserified javascript library, on the fly. Is there a way when I access a node webserver running on http://localhost:3000, it does the following:

> 1. Reads test.html via filestream.
> 2. Creates a browserify bundle starting at ./entry.js.
> 3. Injects that browserify bundle into a script tag within the test.html.
> 4. Sends the page.

Which at this point, would mean I could just save the file (code changes) and reload the page to update.

Comment: Yes, that's one of the things servers typically do. Have you tried it?

Comment: Try `Gulp` or `Grunt`. It actually does what you described and lot more too.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Awesome.

```
var browserify = require('browserify');
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.url === '/bundle.js') {
        res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/javascript');
        var b = browserify(__dirname + '/main.js').bundle();
        b.on('error', console.error);
        b.pipe(res);
    }
    else res.writeHead(404, 'not found')
}).listen(3000);
```